# Unable to install anything on Ubuntu server 16.04.3 (openssh for example)

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3. During the installing I kept getting the message:

> select and install software failed

I have no idea why. I'm not an expert so I had no idea on how to find any reason why that kept happening. Anyway, the OS seemed to have installed just fine so I figured to just install OpenSSH through command line.

First I tried: `sudo apt install openssh-server`. That resulted in the request of the CD. So I modified `etc/apt/sources.list` and commented out the cdrom entry as advised here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194719

Of course I did `sudo apt-get update` after. Which strangly enough returned `Reading package lists... Done` straight after.

After that I tried installing OpenSSH again, which resulted in:

`Unable to locate package openssh-server`.

So perhaps there was something wrong with my internet connection, but `ifconfig` gave me the network interface with the ipaddress I expected. So I think that's working fine.

Next I found some advise to run:

`sudo rm var/lib/apt/lists/*` and do `sudo apt-get update` after. Tried this, but no effect.

I have a feeling my installation simply has no repositories listed at all and therefor can't find any packages of course. Unfortunetely, if this is the case, I have no idea on how to fix it. Any advise would be welcome!

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Only the commented CDROM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell apt where to look for updates (on the net). That means you need to add sources to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

You can have that file generated by this site here, f.ex.; https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Alternatively you can search "ask ubuntu", there are plenty of question about `sources.list`, that should be able to help you further.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've updated the file with that website and everything is working as expected now :) Rly saved my day!